# Nuget package with Unsupported - why?

Tags: nuget, .net-standard, .net-standard-2.0

I have a multitrageted project: `<TargetFrameworks>net451;netstandard2.0</TargetFrameworks>`

And I have a class library targeting `netstandard2.0`, when I try to reference the package I see `.NET Framework 4.5.1` with dependencies, and then just **`Unsupported`** (see pic.).

But I do not know why.

[image]

And here is the nuspec of the package:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2013/05/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata>
    <id>com.luscii.connect.common</id>
    <version>10.0.94</version>
    <authors>Luscii</authors>
    <owners>Luscii</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>Package Description</description>
    <copyright>Copyright 2019 Luscii</copyright>
    <dependencies>
      <group targetFramework=".NETFramework4.5.1">
        <dependency id="System.ComponentModel.Annotations" version="4.6.0" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
      </group>
      <group targetFramework=".NETStandard2.0">
        <dependency id="System.ComponentModel.Annotations" version="4.6.0" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
      </group>
    </dependencies>
  </metadata>
</package>
```

Comment: Which version of NuGet are you using?

Comment: @JoakimSkoog The one which comes with `VS 2019 16.3.1`

Comment: If you run `nuget help` in the Package Manager Console you should see something like `NuGet Version: 2.8.50126.400` at the top

Comment: @JoakimSkoog `Package Manager Console Host Version 5.3.0.6251` `NuGet Command Line 5.3.0.4`

Comment: What does your project file look like? How do you pack and publish the NuGet package?

Comment: @JoakimSkoog  I pack and publish with `dotnet pack` and then old `NuGet publish`. both are steps in TeamCity. It looks like it is a UI bug, because when I reference packages from .NET Core 3 project packages are resolved without problems.